# Selection/Highlight across multiple <li> tags issue

Tags: javascript, range, highlight

Here is my JsFiddle :

[Highlight issue after selecting text across multiple li tags](https://jsfiddle.net/8mdX4/1426/)

and in that i am using the following code which adds span for highlighting the text

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
content = range.extractContents();
span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.className='startIndex-'+startIndex+' endIndex-'+endIndex+'';
span.style.background = 'pink';
span.appendChild(content);
var htmlContent = span.innerHTML;
range.insertNode(span);
```

Here after selecting text across multiple li i am passing start index and end index of selected text in onclick function .

but after clicking the button while highligting it breaks the selected content into new li and keeps on adding new li tags there after

I want to highlight the selected range without affecting the HTML.

Does anyone know how to stop HTML misbehaving and highlight it properly.

Comment: With [mark.js](https://markjs.io) it's possible to highlight across elements

Comment: looked into it..it is nice..but for now what changes i need to make in existing code to make it work...later i will reimplement the whole code as i am in a bit hurry to make the code live...any suggestions for fiddle code?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the style, could you not just add a class?
Javascript:

```
     var el = document.getElementById('hello');
     el.className ="red"
```

CSS

```
.red{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: On pressing the button the html is misbehaving...and HTML elements gets affected..... that's the issue while highlighting

Comment: This is not the actual solution.